# Why is every open set a G-delta set?

Tags: general-topology

Why is every open set a $G_\delta$ set? A set is a $G_\delta$ set if it can be written as a countable intersection of open sets.

Comment: Although many elementary texts use *countable* to mean *countably infinite*, this is not normal usage amongst set theorists: *countable* normally means *finite or countably infinite*, and that is the intended meaning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as the intersection of countably many copies of itself.

Comment: True but unnecessary, since *countable* here has its more usual meaning of *finite or countably infinite*.

Comment: Because of what I said the meaning is the same either way. I agree though, the use of "countable" to mean "countable infinite" is annoying.

Comment: I’m aware of that: that’s why I said that it was true. But the fact remains that it’s unnecessary. Pointing out that in this particular context the more restrictive definition can be used to get the same result as the usual definition is fine, but the OP really should learn what *countable* means here.